# How to get a value from a DataGrid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, datagrid, datatable

Can someone please tell me how to get a value from a data grid I pretty much tried everything:

The code in .aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewInbox" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>

            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In a code behind aspx.vb page, I'm trying to get a string value like this:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridViewInbox.Rows
    If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

    ... ??? ... Dim someString As String = row.Cells(1).Text not working

    End If
Next
```

The part with question marks I need to figure out what goes in there to make sure I am getting a string from data grid. Is there an extra step before calling Cells or is this all I need ???? How do i get the value from inside a data grid ????

UPDATE:

When I try to do this:

```
GridViewInbox.Rows(1).Cells(1).ToString()
```

I get this:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell
```

When I try to do this:

```
GridViewInbox.Rows(1).Cells(1).Text
```

I get nothing blank.

This is how I am binding data grid:

```
GridViewInbox.DataSource = dataTable    <- this here is System.Data.DataTable
GridViewInbox.DataBind()
```

All the data shows. The code I am talking about here is being right after GridViewInbox.DataBind()

UPDATE:

.aspx page TemplateField binding

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="From">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton>From</asp:LinkButton>
    </HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label
              ID="btnOpenFrom"
              runat="server"
              CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "From")%>'>
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "From")%>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle Width="20%" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is my COMPLETE CODE maybe this helps:

```
Public Function GetDataTable () As DataTable
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable("Some Name")
    dataTable.Columns.Add("ItemOne", GetType(String))
    dataTable.Rows.Add(...)  <- add rows data here, it matches the amount of columns
    Return dataTable
End Function

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ...
    GridViewTest.DataSource = GetDataTable()
    GridViewInbox.DataBind()

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridViewTest.Rows
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ... <- trying to get at the value in a datagrid
        End If
    Next
    ... 
End Sub
```

Comment: What error message are you receiving? Your aspx code doesn't seem to include any data. Such as bound field. That might be the reason why you are not receiving any data after execution of for loop.

Comment: @AdityaBokade I just have too much to list here. Everything is working I am able to sort the grid and display data. EVERYTHING IS WORKING !!!! I mean how more clear can I say it!!! My questions is what is the proper way to get a value out of a data grid I need a code based on what i put there assuming everything is working.

Comment: your code I wrote in C#, and perfectly working. I took a gridview, a label, and a button. And on button click I wrote almost same code as yours and it worked. But I wrote in C#.

Comment: I updated the original question with UPDATE part.

Comment: Please tell me what do you mean by "it is not working". Already I can see the text of gridview cells displayed in a label on my pc. If data is displayed in the grid, then it must be extracted using the same code that you have mentioned.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell maybe data somehow in a different format or am I suppose to do something before I get a string???

Comment: Show us a small part of your `ItemTemplate`.  I want to see what type of controls you have in there. And show what method you are doing this looping in.

Answer (score 0):

Rows property of GridView is an object of GridViewRowCollection. Hence, to retrieve one row at a time, you need to use GridViewRow object.
Thats the reason, if you directly use GridViewInbox.Rows(1).Cells(1).ToString(), it will not give you the result.

Try this code. Sorry for posting C# code, as I am a C# developer but I am sure you will be able to convert .

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewInbox.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label1.Text += row.Cells[0].Text + "|" + row.Cells[1].Text + "|" + row.Cells[2].Text;
                Label1.Text += "<br/>";
            }

    }
```

Comment: Okay here is a screen if you can take a look at it. I am doing live debug and it shows me the values as the code executes it is always blank. Always. http://snag.gy/N98U0.jpg

Comment: How are you binding data to your gridview? Are you using data binding? IF YES, try to call this.DataBind() method in Page_Load(). I hope you are trying to retrieve the displayed value in gridview and not trying to enter value in it manually. If your gridview is blank at the beginning, then you cannot expect any value to be displayed!

Comment: HERE is where you are going wrong. The data source can be either of the data sources specified in the "Data" section of toolbox. Such as SqlDataSource. First properly set the data source. Then you will see the proper result. I think you need to go long way if you don't know what I mean here.

Comment: Just try this: GridViewInbox.AutoGenerateColumns = true before GridViewInbox.DataBind().

Comment: I build datagrid manually all the "million methods it has" :) everything is working. I can sort the data, I can see the data, I can update the data. I am using Entity Framework to build the grid. I think the data I am trying to get at it wrapped into something or something maybe not set correctly. Because it works when I bind it and let .NET do its thing it works but when I try to traverse the data manually looking at the values it doesn't.

Comment: In datagrid in .aspx code I am only binding certain columns like column 1 and column 3 so the rest of them not showing. When I do this GridViewInbox.AutoGenerateColumns = true before GridViewInbox.DataBind() everything shows!

Comment: Yes I understand. AutoGenerateColumns will suppress your maual binding work. Try to load only necessary columns from data source to data table. Then set GridViewInbox.AutoGenerateColumns = true. This will  be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for each try:

```
dim x as String = ""
x = row.Cells.Item("ColumnName").Value
```

edit:
You must first bind your grid view to a data-table such as:

```
GridViewInbox.DataSource = dataTable
```

Then there should be a value in the cell you are looking at.
**The dataTable MUST be populated with the rows you are looking for.

Comment: There is no .Value available to me. I have Text and I can do this Text.ToString()

Comment: What about .Text, nothing?

Comment: So there is actually nothing there and there may be a binding issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have controls inside of your ItemTemplate then the proper way is to use FindControl.

Not sure why you would name your Label "btnOpenFrom"?  But use the control's id to find it.

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridViewInbox.Rows
    If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim mylabel As Label = row.FindControl("btnOpenFrom")
        Dim something as string = mylabel.Text

    End If
Next
```

Comment: If I use row.FindControl("InboxId")    <- I have this column in my DataTable I get NullReferenceException was caught

Comment: No, that's not what i mean.  You need to show some of your `ItemTemplate` to us.  And also, where are you doing this looping at?  ItemDataBound event?

Comment: Updated my answer.  You use the Id of the control to find it.  NOT the column name.

Comment: You still didn't show where your looping code is at?  Is it in Page_Load?  ItemDataBound?  Where is it?